# can someone explain me the syntax of '${' and ':' in standalone.xml?

Tags: java, xml, jboss

can someone explain me the syntax of '${' and ':' in standalone.xml of JBoss (for example) , like in :

```
port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}" ?
```

I know 'jboss.socket.binding.port-offset' is a system properties .
so if it is being set - it will overwrite the 0 value?
what is the meaning of the ':' in this context ?

Answer (score 1):

from [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-port-offset-on-jboss-as-wildfly)

> As you can see it contains a Beanshell expression which means, unless the jboss.socket.binding.port-offset is set, it evaluates to 0 so to standard sockets.